# SQL Server 2000 assembly creation alternative way?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, .net-assembly

As far as I know it is not possible to create an assembly on a SQL Server 2000.

I have to add my **C#** code to the DB which generate a special `XML` file.
To start this code I want to use an after trigger on a certain table.

How can I do this on SQL Server 2000?

Comment: You can use `xp_cmdshell` within a trigger to run an external program (`.EXE`) - there's not a way to call .NET code directly in SQL 2000.

Comment: Or upgrade to a version of SQL Server that is actually supported

Comment: Yeah I would also suggest it is time to upgrade.

Comment: and can I send parameters within xp_cmdshell to an external program?

Comment: You can send parameters in the `@command_string` like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29629211/4519059) ;).