# Detecting file size before sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, filesize

We're using the following with a 10MB limit for attachments.

```
EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients         = 'me@me.co.uk',  
    @subject            = 'foo bar',
    @file_attachments   = 'C:\xxx\yyy\myFile.xlsx,
    @body_format        = 'html',
    @body               = 'norf';
```

Is it possible in the SQL Server scripts to check the size of `myFile.xlsx` before running this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution by using Batch Files:

**[C:\FileSize.cmd]**

```
@echo %~z1
```

Now you can get size of `<your_file>` by using that file:

```
DECLARE @t table(filesize int)

INSERT INTO @t
EXEC [xp_cmdshell] @command_string = 'C:\filesize.cmd <your_file>'

SELECT TOP(1) * FROM @t
```

Comment: (upped) I will give this a go tomorrow - looks interesting.